# Cannot boot Ubuntu due to usb device descriptor error

Tags: boot

My device was working fine until I restarted it. I was trying to backup my files from my external harddrive before restarting the device. Now the message is : 
usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error 64
And I also have windows as it is dual boot system and windows is working just fine. 
 I have also tried fsck /dev/sdb3 but I don’t know what should I write instead sdb3.